# Dropdown doesn't open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with my code example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lU0Qcxu0rjxtgumBh8dL?p=preview

I want to call the dropDown directive. I don't know what is wrong.

**I have to use the library version that is on my index.html**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.css" media="screen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Comment: the console says it can't find `compDropDownController.js`

Comment: instead of that...(i correct my script), i don't know why the dropdown directive doesn't open

Answer (score 0):

Please check the directive name & the same usage in .html file, I don't think they match.

Answer (score 0):

Support for using the dropdown directive as a class was removed under [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/192768e109b5c4a50c7dcd320e09d05fedd4298a) commit. You now have to add dropdown and dropdown-toggle attributes.